# How to Configure a ng-grid column name at runtime

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a column in an ng-grid table that contains a certain field.  I need to give it 2 different names based on the currently logged in user.  How can I do that?

Constraints that make it less that straightforward.  The name is loaded via an XHR as appConfig.columnName (stored on $rootScope).

```
columnDefs: 
{
     displayName: "{{ appConfig.columnLabel }}",
```

never interpolates, just displays as {{ appConfig.columnLabel }}

```
columnDefs:
{
     displayName: $rootScope.appConfig.columnLabel,
```

fail sometimes because appConfig might not be defined yet.  (This does work if I load a different view first)

I'm not sure how to wait on appConfig though, it is loaded as a service independent of which view is loading.  And even if I do, how do I defer setting the config on the ng-grid?

Seems like this should be really easy, but is proving difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking @ this issue https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/128 I figured it out.  I move the columnDefs to the $scope like so:

```
$scope.gridColumnDefs = [
    ...
    {
        displayName: $rootScope.appConfig && $rootScope.appConfig.columnLabel ? $rootScope.appConfig.columnLabel : "",
        field: 'something',
    }
    ...
]
```

Let the grid config watch the column defs like so:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
     ...
     columnDefs: 'gridColumnDefs',
     ...
    };
```

Then watch the appConfig object on the $rootScope to await the arrival of the appConfig data and adjust the columnDefs with the title.

```
if(!$rootScope.appConfig.hasOwnProperty('columnLabel')) {
    var unwatch = $rootScope.$watch('appConfig',function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue.employerLabel) {
            _.forEach($scope.gridColumnDefs, function(colDef) {
                if(obj.field == 'something') {
                    colDef.displayName = $rootScope.appConfig.columnLabel;
                }
            });
            unwatch();
            unwatch = angular.noop;   // $destroy listener is going to call unwatch
        }
    });
    $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {  // Don't leak this watcher on the $rootScope
        unwatch();
    });
}
```